# Hibernate OneToOneToOne Mapping

Tags: java, hibernate

I keep getting this error:

```
Error saving identity in IdentityDaoImpl. Reason: org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value: com.domain.Identity.password
```

I've mapped 3 tables on a OneToOneToOne mapping basis.

User -> Account -> Identity

How I have it now, Identity extends Account and Account extends User.

Maybe I'm not mapping correctly. I find it a bit tricky because there's 3 one to one relationships instead of 2...

What's the correct way of doing this?

**EDIT 1:**

I've changed all my merge() methods to save() already but it didn't fix the problem.

**EDIT 2:**

Here is a clean version of my entity:

```
@Entity()
@Table(name = "`user`")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING, name = "type")
@DiscriminatorValue("")
public class User extends ActionSupport implements UserDetails, Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -7480567862246640031L;
private Integer ID;
private String type;
private String password;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "ID")
public Integer getID() {
    return ID;
}

public void setID(Integer ID) {
    this.ID = ID;
}

@Column(name = "type", nullable = false, unique = false, length = 255)
public String getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}

@Override
@Column(name = "password", nullable = false, length = 255)
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can we see how you define the password field on your entity? I guess you're trying to save sth. with a password of `null` and this violates either an `@NotNull` or sth. like `required=true`

Comment: Done... Yes I'm busy with the registration, trying to save a user.

Comment: you specify nullable=false on the password field... try to persist sth. after you did a call to setPassword with some value other than null

Comment: On my register.jsp I have <s:password required="true" label="Password" name="identity.password" />

Comment: I took out nullable = false and length = 255 and now it's working.

Comment: but then I doubt that the text entered in your password field makes it to the database?!

Answer (score 0):

```
Error saving identity in IdentityDaoImpl. Reason: org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value: com.domain.Identity.password
```

Your password and type both fields are nullable false, the Exception clearly shows that you are trying to insert null value in password that can't be null. Also type will not accept null value.